# Tomcat default error page

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, web

I would like to display a custom error page when a specific user exception is thown (CustomException) and display the standard Tomcat error page (the HTTP Status 500 with stacktrace printed) if the exception is different.

So i added in my web.xml :

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/xhtml/commun/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/xhtml/commun/expired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>organization.CustomException</exception-type>
    <location>/xhtml/commun/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

However, when an exception other than CustomException is encountered, the content on the navigator freeze (nothing happens on the client side), and i have this log on server side :

```
nov. 09, 2015 4:12:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet Faces Servlet a généré une exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either HTTP 500 or java.lang.Throwable error page is required in web.xml or web-fragment.xml. Neither was found.
at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handleAjaxException(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:207)
at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handle(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:198)     
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:176)     
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
```

Is it possible to show the default Tomcat error page for specific exception types or error code ?

Comment: What did you not understand in `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either HTTP 500 or java.lang.Throwable error page is required in web.xml or web-fragment.xml. Neither was found`?

Comment: I thought if i don't specify a custom location for an error code or a exception type, then the default tomcat error page will show up. But it seems it's not the case, so i think i'm missing something, i don't know what.

Comment: Use either `<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>` or `<error-code>500</error-code>` as a fallback error page, when no match is found for any of the declared exception types.

Comment: You are using OmniFaces `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`. It is mentioned on the [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler), "*The location of the HTTP error code `500` or the exception type `java.lang.Throwable` is required in order to get the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` to work, because there's then at least a fall back error page whenever there's no match with any of the declared specific exceptions. So, you must at least have either `<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>` or `<error-code>500</error-code>`.*"

Comment: Thank you so i guess it is not possible to do what i want to do